# Fixing the position of a header view within a table view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

As part of my application's design, I have placed an image inside of my `UITableView`'s header.

This header image looks great, until the table is scrolled, moving the header relative to the position being scrolled to/from.

My question is, how do I stop this from happening? I'm assuming I'd have to do it another way, i.e. put a `UIImageView` above the `UITableView` so it has nothing to do with the scrolling. However, I cannot put a `UIImageView` outside of the `UITableViewController`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I used a group tableview as their section headers scroll with the content and don't 'stick' under the navigation bar, i then stretched the tableview to an extra 10 each side, and pushed it 10 points to the left, 'getting rid' of the margins.

I then used custom tableview cells to design my own custom cells.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view controller which has this view hierarchy:

```
view
 \---> header view //set the frame to be the top 200 pixels or whatever you want
 \---> table view // instead of being the top view, the table view is a subview with a frame starting below the header view
```

Set the tableview delegate and datasource and use them as normal

Comment: Thanks your answer works brilliantly, for the header view I have used a UIImageView, is this what you meant?